# Fontspec Breaks the Whole Document

Tags: fonts, fontspec, typography

Lately I've been playing with the [font catalogue](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/) and many of the fonts I'm interested in using use the `fontspec` package. Unfortunately, the compiler produces a ton of errors when I try to use any of the fonts associated with it. Here is an example:

[image: Log with errors]

I saw a thread where another user solved this problem by getting rid of outdated packages, but I don't know if this is the case for me and, if it is, which packages are responsible for the outcome.

This is the LaTeX file, it includes every package I ever used when writing math as well:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{inslrmaj}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\input {RoyalIn.fd}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\royalfamily}{\usefont{U}{RoyalIn}{xl}{n}}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textroyal}{\royalfamily}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{QTDublinIrish}


\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}
\begin{document}
\title{1 2 3 Probando}
\author{F A D}
\date{}
\maketitle


\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[N_3(N_4-N_3+N_3)|N_3]]&=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[N_3(N_4-N_3)|N_3]+\mathbb{E}[N_3^2|N_3]\\
&=\mathbb{E}[N_3]\mathbb{E}[N_1]+\mathbb{E}[N_3^2]\\
&=6*2+6+6^2\\
&=54
\end{align*}

$\floor*{\pi} = \ceil*{{-I_2\pi}}$
papaavi\'on, Mart\'in
$\mathbb{HOLA}$

{\calligra Federico}

{\imajfamily Federico}

The High Cross Debacle

{\textroyal T} he car was delivered to the appropriate address

\normalfont Federico

\end{document}
```

Logfile of simple document with fontspec:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.0 (MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit)  (format=lualatex 2022.1.28)  29 JAN 2022 12:53
 restricted system commands enabled.
**fontspec.tex
(./fontspec.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty"
(C:/Users/feded/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2016/11/21 v6760 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(C:/Users/feded/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex
Package: expl3 2016/11/21 v6760 L3 programming layer (code)
L3 Module: l3bootstrap 2016/06/13 v6596 L3 Bootstrap code
\ucharcat@table=\catcodetable5
L3 Module: l3names 2016/10/13 v6722 L3 Namespace for primitives
L3 Module: l3basics 2016/09/01 v6696 L3 Basic definitions
L3 Module: l3expan 2016/08/19 v6684 L3 Argument expansion
L3 Module: l3tl 2016/08/19 v6692 L3 Token lists
L3 Module: l3str 2016/08/19 v6692 L3 Strings
L3 Module: l3seq 2016/08/19 v6685 L3 Sequences and stacks
L3 Module: l3int 2016/09/07 v6700 L3 Integers
\c_max_int=\count87
\l_tmpa_int=\count88
\l_tmpb_int=\count89
\g_tmpa_int=\count90
\g_tmpb_int=\count91
L3 Module: l3quark 2016/08/19 v6685 L3 Quarks
L3 Module: l3prg 2016/08/18 v6679 L3 Control structures
\g__prg_map_int=\count92
L3 Module: l3clist 2016/08/19 v6685 L3 Comma separated lists
L3 Module: l3token 2016/09/01 v6695 L3 Experimental token manipulation
L3 Module: l3prop 2016/08/19 v6685 L3 Property lists
L3 Module: l3msg 2016/08/19 v6691 L3 Messages
L3 Module: l3file 2016/08/19 v6685 L3 File and I/O operations
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count93
\l__iow_target_count_int=\count94
\l__iow_current_line_int=\count95
\l__iow_current_word_int=\count96
\l__iow_current_indentation_int=\count97
L3 Module: l3skip 2016/08/19 v6692 L3 Dimensions and skips
\c_zero_dim=\dimen103
\c_max_dim=\dimen104
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen105
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen106
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen107
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen108
\c_zero_skip=\skip43
\c_max_skip=\skip44
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip45
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip46
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip47
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip48
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip10
\c_max_muskip=\muskip11
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
L3 Module: l3keys 2016/09/21 v6711 L3 Key-value interfaces
\l_keys_choice_int=\count98
L3 Module: l3fp 2016/11/21 v6761 L3 Floating points
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count99
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count100
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count101
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count102
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count103
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count104
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count105
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count106
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count107
L3 Module: l3box 2016/08/19 v6685 L3 Experimental boxes
\c_empty_box=\box26
\l_tmpa_box=\box27
\l_tmpb_box=\box28
\g_tmpa_box=\box29
\g_tmpb_box=\box30
L3 Module: l3coffins 2016/08/19 v6685 L3 Coffin code layer
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box31
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen109
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen110
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen111
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen112
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen113
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen114
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen115
\c_empty_coffin=\box32
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box33
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box34
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box35
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box36
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box37
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box38
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box39
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen116
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen117
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen118
L3 Module: l3color 2016/06/13 v6596 L3 Experimental color support
L3 Module: l3sys 2015/09/25 v6087 L3 Experimental system/runtime functions
L3 Module: l3candidates 2016/08/19 v6688 L3 Experimental additions to l3kernel
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen119
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen120
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen121
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen122
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen123
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen124
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen125
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen126
\l__box_internal_box=\box40
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen127
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen128
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen129
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen130
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen131
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen132
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen133
L3 Module: l3luatex 2016/08/18 v6679 L3 Experimental LuaTeX-specific functions
)
(C:/Users/feded/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3pdfmode.def
File: l3pdfmode.def 2016/08/18 v6679 L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
\l__driver_color_stack_int=\count108
\l__driver_tmp_box=\box41
))
(C:/Users/feded/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.s
ty
Package: xparse 2016/11/21 v6760 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count109
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count110
\l__xparse_mandatory_args_int=\count111
\l__xparse_processor_int=\count112
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count113
)
Package: fontspec 2016/02/01 v2.5a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 ("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload.sty"
Package: luaotfload 2016/06/16 v2.7 OpenType layout system

    FATAL ERROR
    Luaotfload requires a Luatex version >= 0.95.0.
    Please update your TeX distribution!

...les/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-main.lua:36: version check fa
iled
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    ...les/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-main.lua:36: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
l.49 }
    
The lua interpreter ran into a problem, so the
remainder of this lua chunk will be ignored.

)
Lua module: fontspec 2016/02/01 2.5a Advanced font selection for LuaLaTeX. ("C:
/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty"
Package: fontspec-luatex 2016/02/01 v2.5a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X
\l_fontspec_script_int=\count114
\l_fontspec_language_int=\count115
\l_fontspec_strnum_int=\count116
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen134
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen135
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen136
\g__file_internal_ior=\read1

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2016/06/19 v1.99m Standard LaTeX package

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/euenc/eu2enc.def"
File: eu2enc.def 2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for EU2+lmr on input line 105.

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/euenc/eu2lmr.fd"
File: eu2lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
! Font \EU2/lmr/m/n/10=file:lmroman10-regular:script=latn;+trep;+tlig; at 10pt n
ot loadable: metric data not found or bad.
<to be read again> 
relax 
l.105 \fontencoding\encodingdefault\selectfont
                                            
I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.

) ("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/xelatex/xunicode/xunicode.sty"
File: xunicode.sty 2011/09/09 v0.981 provides access to latin accents and many o
ther characters in Unicode lower plane

(C:/Users/feded/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/latex/tipa/t3enc.def
File: t3enc.def 2001/12/31 T3 encoding

! Font \EU2/lmr/m/sl/10=file:lmromanslant10-regular:script=latn;+trep;+tlig; at 
10pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad.
<to be read again> 
relax 
l.316 }{}
       
I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.

! Font \EU2/lmr/m/it/10=file:lmroman10-italic:script=latn;+trep;+tlig; at 10pt n
ot loadable: metric data not found or bad.
<to be read again> 
relax 
l.316 }{}
       
I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.

! Font \EU2/lmr/bx/n/10=file:lmroman10-bold:script=latn;+trep;+tlig; at 10pt not
 loadable: metric data not found or bad.
<to be read again> 
relax 
l.356 {\bfseries
              \xdef\@bfseriesname{\f@series}}
I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for EU2+lmss on input line 357.

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/euenc/eu2lmss.fd"
File: eu2lmss.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
! Font \EU2/lmss/m/n/10=file:lmsans10-regular:script=latn;+trep;+tlig; at 10pt n
ot loadable: metric data not found or bad.
<to be read again> 
relax 
l.357 {\sffamily
              \xdef\@sffamilyname{\f@family}}
I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.

)
\tipaTiiicode=\count117
\tipasavetokens=\toks14
\tipachecktokens=\toks15
 ("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2016/07/10 v1.0t Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: luatex.def on input line 99.

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def"
File: luatex.def 2016/08/17 v0.01g Graphics/Color for luaTeX

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count118
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen137
\Gin@req@width=\dimen138
))
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \__fontspec_post_arg:w with sig. 'mmO{}' on line 356.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \fontspec with sig. 'om' on line 358.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmainfont with sig. 'om' on line 368.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setsansfont with sig. 'om' on line 378.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmonofont with sig. 'om' on line 388.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmathrm with sig. 'om' on line 402.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setboldmathrm with sig. 'om' on line 410.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmathsf with sig. 'om' on line 418.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmathtt with sig. 'om' on line 426.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontfamily with sig. 'mom' on line 440.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontface with sig. 'mom' on line 456.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \defaultfontfeatures with sig. 't+om' on line 470.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \addfontfeatures with sig. 'm' on line 533.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontfeature with sig. 'mm' on line 544.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newAATfeature with sig. 'mmmm' on line 552.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newopentypefeature with sig. 'mmm' on line 560.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \aliasfontfeature with sig. 'mm' on line 581.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \aliasfontfeatureoption with sig. 'mmm' on line 590.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontscript with sig. 'mm' on line 594.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontlanguage with sig. 'mm' on line 598.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareFontsExtensions with sig. 'm' on line 603.
.................................................
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count119

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg")
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 2629.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 2634.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 2639.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 2644.
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count120
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count121
LaTeX Info: Redefining \em on input line 2660.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \emph on input line 2666.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \- on input line 2670.
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/redefine-command"
. 
. Redefining command \oldstylenums with sig. 'm' on line 2765.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \liningnums with sig. 'm' on line 2769.
.................................................
))
(./fontspec.aux)
\openout1 = fontspec.aux

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for EU2/lmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T3/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T3+cmr on input line 3.

(C:/Users/feded/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd
File: t3cmr.fd 2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.

(C:/Users/feded/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count122
\scratchdimen=\dimen139
\scratchbox=\box42
\nofMPsegments=\count123
\nofMParguments=\count124
\everyMPshowfont=\toks17
\MPscratchCnt=\count125
\MPscratchDim=\dimen140
\MPnumerator=\count126
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count127
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks18
) ("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty"
Package: epstopdf-base 2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty"
Package: grfext 2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty"
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
))
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty"
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty"
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty"
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX detected.
))))
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty"
Package: pdftexcmds 2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)


("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty"
Package: ifpdf 2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/generic/oberdiek/luatex-loader.sty"
Package: luatex-loader 2016/05/16 v0.6 Lua module loader (HO)

(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/scripts/oberdiek/oberdiek.luatex.lua))
\pdftexcmds@toks=\toks19
)
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 43
8.
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)             [.png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PNG,.PDF,.JPG,.JPEG
,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 456.
)
.................................................
. fontspec info: "setup-math"
. 
. Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid this).
.................................................
\symlegacymaths=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \colon on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathdollar on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `EU2' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> EU2/lmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `EU2' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> EU2/lmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  EU2/lmr/m/n --> EU2/lmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> EU2/lmr/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> EU2/lmr/bx/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> EU2/lmss/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> EU2/lmtt/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  EU2/lmr/m/n --> EU2/lmr/bx/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> EU2/lmr/bx/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> EU2/lmss/bx/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> EU2/lmtt/bx/n on input line 3.
 [1

Missing character: There is no h (U+0068) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e (U+0065) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no l (U+006C) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no l (U+006C) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no o (U+006F) in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 1 (U+0031) in font nullfont!
]
(./fontspec.aux))

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 14268 strings out of 495094
 100000,319454 words of node,token memory allocated
 375 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 7 glue, 43 glue_spec, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:13,3:3,4:1,5:10,6:7,7:22,8:1,9:6
 17655 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+200000
 15 fonts using 634455 bytes
 50i,4n,31p,340b,229s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
Output written on fontspec.pdf (1 page, 828 bytes).

PDF statistics: 6 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 100000000)
```

Comment: Don't care about the number of errors. Start with the first. And don't look only at the summary - it can miss important stuff, look at the log-file. You should also make a small complete example and then show it so that we know which code you are actually using. (EU2 sounds as if you have a rather old system, but without code and log-file it is difficult to say more).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I added the LaTeX file, the LaTeX file provided as an example in tug.org also fails to compile on my PC.

Comment: you shouldn't use calligra and fontenc with xelatex. Apart from this: Start with a small document (only `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{fontspec}\begin{document}hello\end{document}`. Add more packages only when that works.

Comment: I used your example and it still fails to compile. Also LuaLaTex is my default compiler. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, I used xelatex separately on a document with fontspec and it worked, I guess I will keep fontspec separate from every other package and use different compilers.

Comment: If my example fails with lualatex show the log file.

Comment: It failed, I added the log to the main post

Comment: Show the real log *file*, not a screenshot of the summary of your editor.

Comment: I think that should be it, sorry for the troubles.

Comment: Ok and now skim through the log until you find the line with FATAL ERROR and read what it says.

Comment: An outdated TeX distribution. "Luaotfload requires a Luatex version >= 0.95.0."

Comment: Exactly.  Your system is from 2016 and outdated. Lualatex will not work. Either update or stick to xelatex.

Comment: Thank you, I'm updating my packages with miktex now.

Comment: @Federico Seems you are running MiKTe 2.9.  The last time I tried to update MiKTeX 2.9 under 64-bit Win7 via MiKTeX console, this ended up with a broken system consisting of binaries for Win10 as well which did not run under Win7. Therefore I recommend not to update MiKTeX2.9 under Win7 any more. Btw, this is the reason why I bailed out and switched to TeX Live.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Thanks, I uninstalled MiKTeX and my editor, and installed TeX live and TeXstudio. I have one last doubt regarding fontspec. Non-dontspec fonts (i.e. calligra) can be used locally as follows: {\calligra Federico} but every example that uses fontspec sets the font as the main font. How can I use fontspec fonts locally?

Comment: Never use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with luatex or xetex but you are picking up an ancient version of fontspec, you should not be using EU2 encoding

Comment: you do not have to set the main font with fontspec see `\newfontfamily` which you can use to define font switching commands

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid `\usepackage{inslrmaj}` with LuaLaTeX. If you *really* want to use it, you should also be aware that the font is only available in bitmap form.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1,TU]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{calligra}
%\usepackage{inslrmaj} % avoid it with LuaLaTeX

\setmainfont{QTDublinIrish}

\newcommand{\imajfamily}{\usefont{T1}{imaj}{m}{n}}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textimaj}{\imajfamily}

\input{RoyalIn.fd}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\royalfamily}{\usefont{U}{RoyalIn}{xl}{n}}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textroyal}{\royalfamily}


\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}

\begin{document}
\title{1 2 3 Probando}
\author{F A D}
\date{}
\maketitle

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[N_3(N_4-N_3+N_3)|N_3]]
&=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[N_3(N_4-N_3)|N_3]+\mathbb{E}[N_3^2|N_3]\\
&=\mathbb{E}[N_3]\mathbb{E}[N_1]+\mathbb{E}[N_3^2]\\
&=6*2+6+6^2\\
&=54
\end{align*}

$\floor*{\pi} = \ceil*{{-I_2\pi}}$
papaavi\'on, Mart\'in
$\mathbb{HOLA}$

{\calligra Federico}

{\imajfamily Federico}

The High Cross Debacle

\textroyal{T} he car was delivered to the appropriate address

\end{document}
```

With the option I gave to `fontenc`, the TU encoding needed for OpenType fonts is the default. Then the commands for choosing other fonts using the T1 encoding can be used safely.

[image]

Comment: What's the disadvantage of bitmap form? Is it "pasting" an image on the page? Is there a way to tell which of the fonts from the [catalogue](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/alphfonts.html) are of this form?