# Margins are not Constant Throughout the Pages

Tags: margins, typography

I want my margins to be the same in every page. The problem is best described by this image:
[image]

For some reason my compiler decided to push every sentence on the second page to the right. Any ideas?

The LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}%OPTIONS CONFIGURE EDITOR BUILD LUALATEX
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{inslrmaj}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\input {RoyalIn.fd}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\royalfamily}{\usefont{U}{RoyalIn}{xl}{n}}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textroyal}{\royalfamily}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\verbatimfont{QTDublinIrish}[NFSSFamily=QTDublinIrish]
\newfontfamily\QTFraktur{QTFraktur}[NFSSFamily=QTFraktur]

\usepackage{duerer}


\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}
\begin{document}
    \title{ {\verbatimfont Peter Kelly} }
    \author{ {\calligra by Federico Dotti} }
    \date{}
    \maketitle
    
{\textroyal {\Huge T}EXT\\
\smallskip

TEXT\\ 
\smallskip

TEXT

        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is the paragraph indent. Use the parskip package if you prefer spaces between paragraphs instead. And don't add `\\ ` everywhere. That is wrong. If you mean the overall margins: see egreg answer.

Comment: That's perfectly normal with two-side typesetting.

Comment: you are explicitly specifying `twoside` on line 1 of your document that enforces different margins on odd and even pages

Comment: you are using `fontspec` so luatex or xetex so should never use  `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` but you have it (twice!!)  This was explained before https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/631926/fontspec-breaks-the-whole-document#comment1575866_631926

Comment: Thank you David, I removed the `twoside` and it is now fixed.

Comment: @Federico well yes but it's kind of pointless (and annoying for people answering) if you just keep posting the same errors again after they have been fixed in previous posts. The question here is unrelated to the fonts but just indicates that the previous answers on your font related question were not used.

Comment: That is true, I shouldn't take for granted the great help that here is found.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define page margin using package `geometry`. Like this `\usepackage[left=1.9cm,right=1.9cm,top=2cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}%set margin of page`. You can change left, right, bottom and top page margin accordingly by changing values of these.

For detailed information about standard a4 page layout and margin, you can find [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Page_size_and_margins).

The `twoside` default margin for `even side` is 79pt and the `odd side` is 28pt, that's the reason it pushes the second-page contents to right. You can find more details [Here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Single_sided_and_double_sided_documents)

Comment: you could do this but by default article uses the same margins on every page, they only change here as that is forced with the `twoside` option so simply not doing that is simpler than re-setting everything with `geometry`

Comment: Hi @DavidCarlisle. So what do you suggest? not to use **twoside**?

Comment: well the _only_ thing twoside does is allow the page layout on odd and even pages to differ, which is exactly what the question asks about.